# How to be notified when a peer is no longer available in the Wi-Fi Direct range?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I am developing an Android application based on the use of *Wifi Direct* API. I have registered in my `Activity` a `BroadcastReceiver` in order to be notified about the  following Wifi Direct events:

```
WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION 
WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION 
WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION  
WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION
```

I believed that any change in the list of peers (the inclusion or exclusion of a peer in the Wifi Direct range) could trigger the `BroadcastReceiver`. In my app, when a new peer is found, its name is correctly included in a `ListView`, but if the peer leaves the wireless range (or if I turn off its Wi-Fi interface), the `BroadcastReceiver` is not invoked (more specifically, the

```
WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION
```

event is not triggered), and the peer name remains in the `ListView`.

I would like to know if there is any manner to deal with this problem, since the peer names are included in the `ListView`, but never excluded. I have already thought in re-initialize the Channel and `WifiP2pManager` instances, but I believe that this will disconnect all peers.

Comment: Call a peer "stale" unless you've heard about (or from) them recently.  Periodically remove stale names.

Comment: cHao, I think that I cannot simply remove them, since the "peer list" update is done when a `WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` is detected (this event is invoked asynchronously by the system after a `discoverPeers(channel, actionListener)` method call). Another problem would be: how long this "garbage collector" should run?

Comment: I would think the library itself would discard peers it can't see anymore (though it might not emit an event for them).  Do you rely solely on the change events to tell you what's going on, or do you occasionally `requestPeers()`?

Comment: I tried both approaches, but no success... I also have used a `Handler` to perform a periodic `requestPeers()` call, but it does not identified any "changes" (in the case, the disconnection of a peer).

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, then.  Without seeing the code, i'm out of guesses.  This seems like it should be a common enough problem, though, that it'd already be accounted for.

Comment: cHao, the code is basically the same of the example `WiFiDirectDemo`. You can reproduce this problem simply running the example. After starting a "Discover" from both devices, the respectively device names will appear in the screen. If you turn off the wifi of one of the devices, and press again the "Discover" button, the device will not disappear! Furthermore, the dialog shown will never be automatically cancelled, since the `onPeersAvailable()` method from the `PeerListListener` interface is never called.

Comment: Hi @Abhishekchoudhary. Unfortunately, I could not solve that problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: no ...i dont get any soln for dis

Comment: @Rafael I'm also facing the same problem now. I'm going to start a bounty, maybe someone can help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> I believed that any change in the list of peers (the inclusion or exclusion of a peer in the Wifi Direct range) could trigger the BroadcastReceiver.

Yes, I think this should happen.

> In my app, when a new peer is found, its name is correctly included in a ListView, but if the peer leaves the wireless range (or if I turn off its Wi-Fi interface), the BroadcastReceiver is not invoked (more specifically, the WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION event is not triggered), and the peer name remains in the ListView.

We can try to dig through the source code and see if we can explain this behavior.

Note: I don't have a solution to offer. But, the following research might help you understand the 'issue' better.

We'll start here: `WifiP2pSettings` [Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pSettings.java)

This is the fragment you see when you go to *Settings > Wifi > Wifi-Direct*. If you go through the code, you'll notice that the implementation is quite similar to `WifiDirectDemo` project - the `BroadcastReceiver` listens for the same four actions (and two more - one for UI update). The reason why we're looking at this fragment is to check if the demo itself is flawed. But, it looks like the demo is alright.

Moving on - let's see who's broadcasting the action `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` - ultimately, we're interested in finding out why this *isn't* happening as soon as a device goes offline/out of range. This takes us to `WifiP2pService` [Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/p2p/WifiP2pService.java).

The method `WifiP2pService # sendPeersChangedBroadcast()` issues the broadcast:

```
private void sendPeersChangedBroadcast() {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_P2P_DEVICE_LIST, new WifiP2pDeviceList(mPeers));
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REGISTERED_ONLY_BEFORE_BOOT);
    mContext.sendBroadcastAsUser(intent, UserHandle.ALL);
}
```

From looking at `WifiP2pService`, you can tell that `sendPeersChangedBroadcast()` is called in response to several events. We're interested in this one: `WifiMonitor.P2P_DEVICE_LOST_EVENT` [Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiMonitor.java):

```
....
case WifiMonitor.P2P_DEVICE_LOST_EVENT:
    device = (WifiP2pDevice) message.obj;
    // Gets current details for the one removed
    device = mPeers.remove(device.deviceAddress);
    if (device != null) {
        sendPeersChangedBroadcast();
    }
    break;
....
```

`WifiMonitor # handleP2pEvents(String)` is responsible for sending the message that lands in the above-mentioned `case`. Go up the chain to find `MonitorThread` - a static inner class in `WifiMonitor`. `MonitorThread # dispatchEvent(String)` calls the `handleP2pEvents(String)` method.

Finally, something interesting. Look at the `run()` method of `MonitorThread`:

```
private static class MonitorThread extends Thread {

    ....

    public void run() {
        //noinspection InfiniteLoopStatement
        for (;;) {
            String eventStr = mWifiNative.waitForEvent();
            ....
        }
    }

    ....
}
```

- first, we're inside an infinite-loop.
- second, `mWifiNative.waitForEvent()` tells me that its *probably* a blocking call.

These two points put together indicate to me that I am not going to get a prompt response out of this - well, definitely nothing 'instant-like'. The method that we reached by going up the chain - `MonitorThread # dispatchEvent(String)` - is called from inside this infinite loop.

Let's check if something can support our educated guess:

Take a look at `WifiNative` class [Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiNative.java), especially the method `setScanInterval(int)`. This method is called from class `WifiStateMachine` [Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiStateMachine.java). Go through the method `processMessage(Message)`:

```
....
case WifiP2pService.P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED:
    NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo) message.obj;
    mP2pConnected.set(info.isConnected());
    if (mP2pConnected.get()) {
        int defaultInterval = mContext.getResources().getInteger(
                            R.integer.config_wifi_scan_interval_p2p_connected);
        long scanIntervalMs = Settings.Global.getLong(mContext.getContentResolver(),
                            Settings.Global.WIFI_SCAN_INTERVAL_WHEN_P2P_CONNECTED_MS,
                            defaultInterval);

        // ====>> Interval defined here
        mWifiNative.setScanInterval((int) scanIntervalMs/1000);
    } else if (mWifiConfigStore.getConfiguredNetworks().size() == 0) {
        if (DBG) log("Turn on scanning after p2p disconnected");
            sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(CMD_NO_NETWORKS_PERIODIC_SCAN,
                            ++mPeriodicScanToken, 0), mSupplicantScanIntervalMs);
    }
....
```

Notice the `defaultInterval` in the first `if block`. It's requesting `R.integer.config_wifi_scan_interval_p2p_connected` which is defined in `config.xml` [Link](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/config.xml) as:

```
<!-- Integer indicating wpa_supplicant scan interval when p2p is connected in milliseconds -->
<integer translatable="false" name="config_wifi_scan_interval_p2p_connected">60000</integer>
```

60000 ms. That's 1 minute. So, if `Settings.Global.WIFI_SCAN_INTERVAL_WHEN_P2P_CONNECTED_MS` is not set, the scans will be spaced 1 minute apart.

Since, `WIFI_SCAN_INTERVAL_WHEN_P2P_CONNECTED_MS` is placed under global settings, we cannot change it. In fact, it can't even be read. Meaning, the only guarantee we have here is that the list of peers *will* be refreshed in under a minute. The interval can of course vary from brand to brand.

To verify this, I ran the demo on an asus tablet and a dell tablet. Like you said, device coming online was noticed fairly quickly (during the discovery phase). On switching wifi off, I clocked the response. The offline device was taken off the list *automatically* - with a substantial delay. The dell tablet took close to `60 seconds` to notice that asus is offline. Asus on the other hand took `45 seconds`.

To me, this seems like a limitation enforced by android. I cannot tell why. I hope that someone here can offer you a solution - possibly take this research and explore further. But I wouldn't be surprised if a solution did not exist (at present).

Comment: A very comprehensive explanation! Thanks