# Android WiFi Direct WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION never received

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I'm trying to make a multiplayer game for Android via WiFi direct. I followed the instructions on http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html in order to connect to devices.

The ActionListener i use with `discoverPeers()` returns successfully, but then i never receive the `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` intent upon which i would call `requestPeers()`. Strangely when i go into WiFi direct system settings on one device, the other is able to successfully detect it through my app. Do i need to make my device discoverable in my app or something? I haven't found anything to indicate that in the Android developer resources regarding WiFi P2P. There is WiFi direct for service discovery, but that's something else entirely, isn't it?

Comment: Same problem here.  Ever track down what the issue was?

Comment: Answer here is a bit dated, but may show you where to look: [How to be notified when a peer is no longer available in the Wi-Fi Direct range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21072081/how-to-be-notified-when-a-peer-is-no-longer-available-in-the-wi-fi-direct-range).

Comment: did you find a solution ??

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `discoverPeers()` on other devices as well.
Now you will receive the `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION` intent

Answer (score 0):

Add `WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CANGED_ACTION` into your broadcast receiver intent-filter.

Comment: Well, yes. As i said, i followed the instructions on http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html. I'm not sure what other information to provide. I could post code, but it looks like the one in the official example, so that wouldn't be very interesting either.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find devices under Settings/Wifi/Direct Wifi/Available devices

Answer (score 0):

There are two factors contributing to the problem:

1. The event never occurred and not broadcast to others.
2. Although the event occurred, the intent filter does not catch it.

In my case, I found that the receiver does not get the event properly.
the reason was because I didn't registerReceiver to the intent filter properly.

after I do

```
intentFilter.addAction(WifiP2PManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION),
```

I didn't do

```
ct.registerReceiver(bReceiver, intentFilter).
```

ct is activity or context, and
bReceiver is WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver. I firstly wrote

```
ct.registerReceiver(bReceiver, intentFilter),
```

but, it was not executed properly.